# Find number of ways to create sequence A of length n satisfying m conditions

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, dynamic-programming

Find number of ways to create sequence A of length n satisfying m conditions. This sequence A should consist of only non negative numbers. Each condition is described by three integers (i,j,k) signifying max(A[i],A[j])=k.
It is guaranteed that each index of the sequence will be there in at least one condition i.e. there will be finite number of such sequences.
The maximum value of n will not exceed 18 and maximum value of k will not exceed 20000.

I tried it using dynamic programming but the time complexity came out to be exponential. Can you suggest me any better approach which will reduce the time complexity?

Comment: Do you know what the difficulty of the problem is intended to be?  Without thinking about it too much yet, it seems like it is possibly similar to 2SAT which is polytime, although problems of the sort are usually not considered beginner/easy problems.

Comment: It is intended to be medium/hard level of problem.

Comment: oh, n is only up to 18?  Then a `O(2^n)` solution should be considered tractable, and is probably what the `n=18` constraint is hinting at.

Comment: what is the constraint on `m`?

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do it in O(2^n)?

Comment: m can take maximum value equal to n^2.

Comment: As stated, this problem is easy.  For each `i`, intersect the conditions and you get that `A[i] < K[i]`.  Then the answer is `K[0] * K[1] * ... * K[n-1]`.  Is there some missing condition to make it trickier such as no repeated values?

Comment: `max(A[i],A[j])=k` either means `A[i]=k and A[j]<=k` or `A[i]<=k and A[j]=k`. So each of the `m` conditions represents a binary choice: choose either `A[i]=k` or `A[j]=k`. Some of those choices are contradictory. For example given (0,1,10) and (0,2,20), you can't choose `A[0]=20` because that violates the first condition. Thus, `A[2]=20`.

Comment: @btilly The value of k[i] will change depending upon what values we assign to other a[i] 's.

Comment: @user3386109 how will you calculate number of different sequences using this fact?

Comment: For each valid set of choices, each A[i] is either one value, or X+1 values where X is the smallest `k` in any condition that affects A[i].

Comment: @user3386109 Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: Ah.  You are right.  I missed the importance of the =.

Comment: Is this a homework or from a competition? There is another person asking the exact same question. Please disclose the source.

Comment: @justhalf This question was also posted on [CS.SE (deleted by question author)](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/128110/), where it was pointed out to be part of [this ongoing contest problem](https://www.codechef.com/JULY20A/problems/LCMCONST).

Comment: @Discretelizard Thanks for the info. The contest problem looks slightly different (LCM instead of MAX), which requires different solving strategy. But I'm not sure whether this makes it okay for SO. I'm flagging this question.

Comment: @justhalf If k is prime, then `LCM(a,b)=k` is equivalent to the condition `max(a,b)=k`. I believe you can reduce the contest problem to cases where you may assume B_i is prime, which then gives you the current question.

Comment: Good point. I just thought it would be lucky to have two question posing it in the same form, different from the original. But what you said makes sense.

Comment: @Discretelizard Really? If `LCM(a,b)=k` and `k` is prime, then the solution to `max(a,b)=k` of `a=b=k` doesn't work.

Comment: @btilly True, they're not actually equivalent. Still, `LCM(a,b)=k` does imply `max(a,b)=k` when k is prime. Also, the solution with `a=b` is the only solution to the max condition not satisfying LCM. So, counting all sequences with the max condition and subtracting the sequences where the values are equal (should be easy to check if you explicitly enumerate them, not sure if there is a risk of double-counting otherwise, but it sounds doable) should give the solution for the lcm condition.

Comment: @Discretelizard I am still dubious.  `a+1 = b = k` is another solution to `max(a,b)=k` that generally does not satisfy `LCM(a,b)=k`.

Comment: @btilly Hmm, yes indeed, there are more solutions to max than lcm. Then I guess there must be more going on than I thought. I admit that I didn't think about this very deeply: another user on the now deleted copy of this question on CS.SE claimed that this question is a sub-problem of the contest problem without any further details, and this relation is what I thought was the key idea.

Answer (score 3):

Following user3386109's suggestion, decompose each input constraint max(A[i], A[j]) = k into three constraints:

- A[i] ≤ k
- A[j] ≤ k
- A[i] = k ∨ A[j] = k

We can count solutions using a DPLL-like backtracking procedure. First, the equivalent of unit propagation:

- Given two constraints A[i] ≤ k<sub>1</sub> and A[i] ≤ k<sub>2</sub>, we can keep A[i] ≤ min(k<sub>1</sub>, k<sub>2</sub>) and discard the other.
- Given two constraints A[i] = k<sub>1</sub> and A[i] ≤ k<sub>2</sub>, either we can drop the latter (if k<sub>1</sub> ≤ k<sub>2</sub>) or declare that there are no solutions (otherwise).
- Given two constraints A[i] ≤ k<sub>1</sub> and A[i] = k<sub>2</sub> ∨ A[j] = k<sub>2</sub>, if k<sub>1</sub> < k<sub>2</sub>, then we can simplify the latter to A[j] = k<sub>2</sub>.
- Given two constraints A[i] = k<sub>1</sub> and A[i] = k<sub>2</sub> ∨ A[j] = k<sub>2</sub>, either we can drop the latter (if k<sub>1</sub> = k<sub>2</sub>) or simplify it to A[j] = k<sub>2</sub> (otherwise).

If all constraints are of the first two types, we can count the number of solutions by taking the product of (k + 1) for each k that is the right-hand side of a non-redundant inequality constraint.

Otherwise, there is a constraint A[i] = k ∨ A[j] = k. We make two recursive calls: one with the extra constraint A[i] = k and one with the extra constraint A[i] ≤ k - 1 (we know that A[i] > k is impossible).

The depth of the recursive tree is at most n, since each child call fixes more variables than its parent after unit propagation. Hence the search tree has O(2<sup>n</sup>) nodes, each of which should be decently cheap.

Comment: In the case where you take the minimum constraint, you do not discard the other, you instead assign the other node to be the limit.

Comment: Two other observations.  We can create a graph by using entries as nodes and yet to be satisfied constraints as edges.  This leads to two good shortcuts.  1) Unconnected components can be solved separately from each other and the answers multiplied together.  2) Always pick the node connected to the most edges to guess next.